# haskell, list of lists with a specific form (list comprehension)

Tags: list, haskell, set, list-comprehension

i want to create a functions that takes a list and creates a list of list with list comprehension with the form `[[e1],[e1,e2],[e1,e2,e3]...]`.

For example:

```
f5 ['a','b','c'] = ["a","ab","abc"]
f5 [1,2,3] = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

My Code:

```
f5 xs = [a | a <- xs]

-- tests:
*Main> f5 ["a","b","c"]
["a","b","c"]
*Main> f5 [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: your two inputs don't have the same types.  Perhaps you meant `['a','b','c']`

Comment: You are right, i will change it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
f5 xs = [take index xs | (x, index) <- zip xs [1..]]
```

For each element in the list a tuple is created containing that element and it's index, starting at 1. Then, by using `take`, for each element in the zipped list an appropriate number of elements from the original list is taken. The number of elements to take is specified in the index.

Actually, we don't even need the `x` element from the tuple, so this could be rewritten as

```
f5 xs = [take index xs | (_ ,index) <- zip xs [1..]]
```

Comment: you actually just need the length, can be simplified? to `f5 xs = [take i xs | i <- [1..(length xs)]]`

Comment: @karakfa Thanks. How do you guys come up with such good answers all the time? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
foldr (\x rest -> [x]:(map (x:) rest)) [] [1,2,3,4]
```